# ScrollView kills my android app, and I don't understand something about the table view

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scrollview

I'm writing a small application for my nexus 7 tablet, and I have a strange error. To my understanding the following `xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
  <ScrollView>
    <TableRow
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="2dip">
      <EditText
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:hint="name"
      android:inputType="text"
      android:textSize="20sp"/>
      <TextView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="20sp"
      android:text="smells more like prey than a hunter."/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="2dip">
      <TextView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="20sp"
      android:text="The spirits spoke to me of a great danger that follows"/>
      <EditText
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:hint="name"
      android:inputType="text"
      android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </TableRow>
  </ScrollView> 

</TableLayout>
```

should produce a scrollable app with two lines, each with a text field with gray `name` written in it, with the text wrap around it and additional text that will be written before or after the text that will try and fill the screen. When I compile this, however, the application crash (`unfortunately, has stopped`). If I remove the `ScrollView` attribute, The two lines are of the same length, with the `EditText` taking half the space on each line while in landscape mode. In portrait mode, the first line holds only the `EditText` field and the second one only the `TextView` field. It seams to me that the table tries to fit the two lines into the same length, but I can't understand why.

How can I fix this? 
Comment:
I'm using a library structure generate by [aide](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui), which I use only to compile my code on the tablet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your table layout all inside the scrollview. scrollview can onlyhost one direct child, but that child can have many children! also you still need a height and width for scrollview

here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
      <EditText
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:hint="name"
      android:inputType="text"
      android:textSize="20sp"/>
      <TextView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
      android:textSize="20sp"
      android:text="smells more like prey than a hunter."/>
    </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
   <EditText
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:hint="name"
      android:inputType="text"
      android:textSize="20sp"/>

      <TextView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="20sp"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:text="The spirits spoke to me of a great danger that follows"/>

  </LinearLayout>

</TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

should work for u.

try the above layout instead of yours and let me know if it helps. to tell the truth i think you want a listview and an adapter...

Comment: This works, but I have some issues. Mostly, I want to center most of the lines, and align others to the left. To my understanding, the ``ListView" doesn't allow for more complex line styles, but I'm still confused about it

Comment: it will do what you want, but as for here... change gravity of textviews u wish to align on the left, to left, or remove it completely.                  with a listview you can create a custom adapter however u want, and when your making duplicate items with the same layout but with different properties as you are its probably best. a lot less xml as well

Comment: Cool, thanks. I tried to search a guide for ``ListView`` and ``adapter`` that does something which is not a list of text and I couldn't find any. Where can I find data about this?